# MVC C# Changing Database Structure Without Dropping Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I add a property to a class or add an entire class to the `DbSet` in my database file, Entity Framework should automatically add tables columns accordingly. This is working fine, but my issue is dropping the entire database and recreating it.

The remote server I am using doesn't allow me to recreate the database through Visual Studio and I must go and make an entire new database manually if I add/change classes/properties. Also, it won't let me delete the reference to the database even though it technically has been deleted so I have to rename the new database to another name.

Is there any way that I can change the structure of my database easily without dropping and recreating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Use Entity Framework migrations. Start from executing this from your package manager console:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

Here is an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj591621.aspx) on MSDN about it. You have an option of using migrations only if you use Entity Framework Code First approach.

The cool thing about EF migrations is that you have automatic migrations option that you can enable. Basically all your schema changes that would not affect data integrity or loss (e.g. adding columns or new tables) in your database can be automatically pushed without explicitly implementing migration.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3330265 you're welcome. Good luck with migrations!

Answer (score 0):

## Requirements

Install Entity Framework to your Visual Studio Application

## Steps

1. Import The CodeFirst Model
   (You seems to already have your model in hand, just make sure it is a Code First Model.)
2. Use the package manager Console in VS and run :

   `Add-Migration -IgnoreChanges`
3. On your model object, make any desired Changes
4. Redo the Add-Migration command without the -IgnoreChanges flag

   `Add-Migration`
5. Update the Database

   `Update-Database`

## Notes

You may add options and C# files to control your migration

`Update-Database -ProjectName Model -StartUpProjectName Model -Verbose
    -ConfigurationTypeName SpecialConfigurationForThisMigration`

#### SpecialConfigurationForThisMigration.cs

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Model.Model>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Customer\\Migrations";
        }

        protected override void Seed(Model.Model context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.

        }
    }
```